# ASP.NET: серверные элементы управления (с префиксом ASP) обрабатываются на сервере через C#, VB или на клиенте, через JS?

Tags: c#, веб-программирование, asp.net, iis

Допустим, имеется кнопка (не `submit`, а обычная кнопка), с префиксом `asp` (`asp:button`) и атрибутом `runat = server`.

На события "клик" у нее в codebehind есть обработчик написанный на C#/VB/managed C++. Но, браузер, конечно, не понимает C#/VB/managed C++ и здесь я запутался, т. к. есть 2 способа обработки:

1. для того чтоб обработать событие клик браузер, после клика посылает запрос на сервер, и сервер, запускает dll-ку, в котором есть код для обработки клика по кнопке.
2. Сервер перед отправкой страницы браузеру с самого начала код обработки клика написанный на C#/VB/managed C++ переводит в Javascript, и вместе с страницей отсылает браузеру js-сценарий, и при клике по кнопке обрабатывался cценарий, написанный js.

**Вопрос:** ASP.NET: серверные элементы управления (с префиксом `ASP`) обрабатываются на сервере через C#, VB или на клиенте, через JS?
Заранее спасибо.

Comment: (с префиксом ASP и атрибутом runat=server)

Comment: Сервер обрабатывает только get и post запросы, код обработчика генит C#/VB/managedc++, а уже события post генерирует js.  При компиляции asp генерируется и код(dll) и js - поэтому можно считать что оно выполняется с двух сторон.

Answer (score 1):

Работает первый сценарий.

При клике на кнопку c `runat=server`, у которой указан аттрибут OnClick делается запрос на сервер. На сервере создается заново класс страницы со всеми контролами, заново создается C#-объект типа Button, в них загружается состояние из ViewState. У объекта Button вызывается событие `Click`.

После обработки события состояние сохраняется обратно во ViewState, страница заново отрисоваывается, и отправляется клиенту.